# Parsing & Sorting csv file by Line

Tags: c++, file, parsing

Got this csv file of my jump logbook and wish to sort within each block (Jump Record), so that intructor is listed first, student second and optional cameraman last.
Current they are written in various order.

Was thinking of reading and assigning each line of the block into vars and then printing using the blank line as a loop contron. Am I on the right track?
Would prefer solution help in C++ (little bit of exp. and a compiler setup), but am flexi and  looking to really get into the nuts and bolt of any reccommended language this summer. Possible Python or any one with a good book intro to CompSci.

Any advice & ref much appreciated!

first col is role: 1,2,3.

role(1,2,3),date (yyymmdd), aircraft-liftnumber, name
role 1 is a tandem instructor,
role 2 is a student,
role 3 freefall camera (optional)

1,20100124,C206WR-L1,MAC PETE

2,20100124,C206WR-L1,HOWARD STEPH

3,20100124,C206WR-L1,JONES DAVE

,,,

2,20100124,C206WR-L3,ALLSOP BEX

1,20100124,C206WR-L3,MAC PETE

3,20100124,C206WR-L3,JONES DAVE

,,,

1,20100124,C206WR-L2,MAC PETE

3,20100124,C206WR-L2,LAUER FINCH

2,20100124,C206WR-L2,JONES DAVE

,,,

1,20100124,C206WR-L4,MAC PETE

3,20100124,C206WR-L4,LAUER FINCH

2,20100124,C206WR-L4,JONES DAVE

,,,

2,20100124,C206WR-L4,SMITH JOHN

1,20100124,C206WR-L4,MAC PETE

,,,

2,20100124,C206WR-L5,BROWN CLAIRE

3,20100124,C206WR-L5,JONES DAVE

1,20100124,C206WR-L5,MAC PETE

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a std::multimap to sort them while inserting and also not to lose any data since multimap can have multiple same key values. (Key values will be the role numbers in this case.) Therefore the data will be sorted as you wanted.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, the OP wants to sort each line, not sort all the lines into a map.

Comment: Ok then for each block of data he needs to use a std::map (since key value repetition will not occur) and each block is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a split function to break down each CSV line into a `vector<string>` of variables.  Here's an example split function which can be called with a std::string and a char delimeter (which in your case would be ","):

```
template<typename T>
static inline std::vector<std::basic_string<T>> split(const std::basic_string<T>& s, T c)
{
    std::vector<std::basic_string<T>> v;

    if (!s.length())
        return v;

    std::basic_string<T>::size_type i = 0, j = s.find(c);

    while (j != std::basic_string<T>::npos)
    {
        v.push_back(s.substr(i, j - i));
        i = ++j;
        j = s.find(c, j);
    }

    v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));

    return v;
}
```

Then you could simply print out the variables in the order you choose.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat, I'll show one, which is closer to me: use a parser generator (e.g. AXE, Spirit). Since I'm intimately familar with AXE, here is a C++ grammar of your data structure:

```
using axe::shortcuts;

// for role you can use a digit, you can additionally contrain it
auto role_rule = _d;
// or you can use char literals instead
// auto role_rule = axe::r_any("123");

// for date you can use digits or axe::r_decimal, depending on what you want to do with it
auto year_rule = axe::r_many(_d, 4);
auto month_rule = _d & _d;
auto date_rule = _d & _d;

// aircraft-liftnumber: as far as I understand it's alpha-numeric
auto aircraft_rule = +_w & '-' & +_w;

// name is two alpha strings separated by spaces
auto first_name_rule = axe::r_alphastr();
auto last_name_rule = axe::r_alphastr();
auto name_rule = last_name_rule & +_ws & first_name_rule;

// a rule to extract all information from the line
std::string line; // read line from file
struct record {
unsigned role, year, month, day;
std::string aircraft, name;
};

record rec;

auto line_rule = role >> rec.role & ','
& year_rule >> rec.year & ','
& month_rule >> rec.month & ','
& day_rule >> rec.day & ','
& aircraft_rule >> rec.aircraft & ','
& name_rule >> rec.name & *_n;

std::vector<record> file_records;

auto file_rule = *(line_rule >> axe::e_ref([&](...)
{
   file_records.push_back(rec);
})) & _z;

// read your file to a vector without filtering
std::ifstream csv_file("filename", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> cvs_content(
   std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(cvs_file), 
   std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

if(!file_rule(cvs_content.begin(), cvs_content.end()).matched())
   throw "file corrupt";
```